# How to write in a id of form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to write in a textarea but i have two "id" equal because i create the form for changing data.
If the form is:

```
<form method="GET" name="formparam" id="formparam" action="${nextstep}">
    <label>ID</label></td><td>
    <textarea class="expand" name="inputp'+v+'_id" id="inputp'+v+'_id">
    </textarea>
</form>
```

And for Call i use this script:

```
function qs(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[*+?^$.\[\]{}()|\\\/]/g, "\\$&"); // escape RegEx control chars
    var match = location.search.match(new RegExp("[?&]" + key + "=([^&]+)(&|$)"));
    return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function Pcompila(v){
var i;
var Listparam=['_id','_description','_info','_type','_value'];
for (i=0;i<Listparam.length;i++)
{
var a ='inputp'+v+ Listparam[i];
alert(a);
    if (location.search) {
    var p=qs(a);
    alert(p);
            $('#'+a).text(p);

    }
}

        return;
    }
```

Where `$('#'+a).text(p);` is wrong because don't write.
How to change for calling the id in a form???.
I try with this:

```
$("formparam").$('#'+a).text(p);
```

This is a absolute wrong!!!

Comment: Really confusing question to figure out what you are asking.

Comment: Try to be more clear on your question unable to understand

Comment: @Layke absolutely agree. By what I got from the first sentence, you have two inputs with the same id. This is never going to work at all, as ids should be always unique. You could put those equal id into another param (let's call it data-id) and get the correct item from there `$('[data-id='+a+']').text(p)`

Comment: Only i have two id equal and this script not write.
I want to write in a form and not in other div.

Comment: I want to write to a id that is in the form

Comment: number en integer 1 2 3 4 5 6.
One number

Comment: 2 things still ambiguous, var p=qs(a); what is qs? and I hope no 2 tags have been given same id?

Comment: The problem is only $("formparam").$('#'+a).text(p);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("formparam")` is not correct because `formparam` is not an element type, it should be `#formparam` to search for an ID. And the way to search for one element inside another is to use `.find()`, e.g. `$("#formparam").find("#"+a)`. But since IDs must be unique, you don't really need to say where to search for them, so you can just use `$("#"+a)`, as in Pulkit Mittal's answer.

Comment: I know that ("formaparam") is wrong but now i try $("#formparam").find("#"+a).val(p);

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the way you're updating the value of the textarea.

It should be:

```
$('#'+a).val(p);
```

And please make sure no 2 elements have same id.

EDIT: If you really need more than one element to have same id, you will have to go through a different path.

```
$('#formparam').find('textarea.expand').val(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for the you response.
I need the two same id because after id how can I edit data on the querystring?
I open the new form for changing data

Comment: I don't have the permission Pulkit...I don't have 15 reputation

Comment: No problem brother, I just hope it helps.